# Embedding Word Object into VB.Net Winform

Tags: vb.net, winforms, embedding

I wondering if its possible to use Microsoft Word as a text editor in a VB.Net project?

My project currently uses a Rich Text Box to allow the user to right a report which is then saved and a report generated. I was wondering if i could switch to Word for better formatting and layout options, be it embedded in the actual form or in another form thats called (if that makes it easier to assign the control).

I have worked on opening Word itself via a button click but would like to have it incorporated in the project. All users that would actually use the program would have one of the more recent versions of word installed.

Any pointers to websites would be great as i'm constantly searching but not getting very far

Thanks

Comment: The RTF that Word generates is not that compatible with RichTextBox.  Fancy formatting isn't going to look the same, RTB just isn't a substitute for a full-blown word processor.  You'd be better off with WordPad.  And [move up](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23717718/did-win8-add-built-in-spell-checker-for-legacy-apps-too/23721184#23721184) to the RichTextBox version that WordPad uses so you can be 100% sure it will look the same.  Neither are embeddable, OLE is dead.

Comment: there is a fairly well done [FastColoredTextBox](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/161871/Fast-Colored-TextBox-for-syntax-highlighting) on codeproject; it isnt RTF and is mainly for syntax or text highlighting, but it might work for you anyway.